# Using jQuery Masonry Many times in the same site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery masonry 3 times on the same site. Each code block works independently but when trying to use all 3 at once, only the last one works. How can I combine these to work yet keep the different values and selectors each has?

```
/** First Instance **/
    var $container = $('.smallcolwrap');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.smallcol',
            columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                return containerWidth / 3; },
            isAnimated: true
          });
        });

    /** Second Instance **/
    var $container = $('.slickr-flickr-gallery');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : 'li',
            columnWidth: 160,
            isAnimated: true
          });
        });

    /** Third Instance **/  
    var $container = $('.navigationHome');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : 'li',
            columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                return containerWidth / 2; },
            isAnimated: true,
                animationOptions: {
                duration: 250,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
                }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Give each `var $container` variable a unique name, otherwise each one will overwrite the previous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, thanks Kevin. I'm not a JS expert but that was easy. That is what happens after staring too long at this.

```
/** First Instance **/
var $container = $('.smallcolwrap');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.smallcol',
        columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
            return containerWidth / 3; },
        isAnimated: true
      });
    });

/** Second Instance **/
var $container1 = $('.slickr-flickr-gallery');
    $container1.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container1.masonry({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        columnWidth: 160,
        isAnimated: true
      });
    });

/** Third Instance **/  
var $container2 = $('.navigationHome');
    $container2.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container2.masonry({
        itemSelector : 'li',
        columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
            return containerWidth / 2; },
        isAnimated: true,
            animationOptions: {
            duration: 250,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
            }
      });
    });
```