# Masonry and imagesLoaded error

Tags: jquery-masonry, imagesloaded

I combined masonry with imagesLoaded like this:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.masonry-container');
var msnry;
    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            itemSelector: '.masonry-item'
        }).resize();
});
```

But getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

What am I doing wrong.

**Edit**

I'm having two masonry calls, maybe that causes problem, another one is the same, one after another:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.gallery');
var msnry;
    // initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
    imagesLoaded( container, function() {
        var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
            itemSelector: '.gallery-item'
        }).resize();
});
```

Comment: Why are you calling `resize()` within imagesloaded?

Comment: I need it, I put it outside, but nothing changes

Comment: You haven't provided enough code. A jsfiddle would help.

Comment: It's a wordpress site, so code is generated gallery, but here is example of code in fiddle, you can only look at js. https://jsfiddle.net/n7svvw8b/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a problem. In masonry call I had `var container` twice which just overwrites one another. Ex. in specific page I just had div with class `.gallery` but not `.masonry-container`, and `var container` is overwritten with `.masonry-container` which doesn't exists, so it returns `null`. Solution is:

```
var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.masonry-item'
    });
});

var $container2 = $('.gallery');
    $container2.imagesLoaded(function(){
    $container2.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.gallery-item'
    });
});
```

As seen here: [Using jQuery Masonry Many times in the same site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955592/using-jquery-masonry-many-times-in-the-same-site)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors in your jsfiddle which I assume are in your page as well. First, id's are unique, you can't have multiple id's of the same name (id="galery-item"). Your calling masonry on  ".gallery" yet you only have the id="gallery", no class="gallery", and finally you set your itemSelector: '.gallery-item', yet even if you had the figures set as a class, you have it called galery-item.

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/duyeckyr/) with classes and id's set correctly.

js:

```
var container = document.querySelector('.gallery');
var msnry;
// initialize Masonry after all images have loaded
imagesLoaded( container, function() {
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.galery-item'
    });
});
```

working html:

```
<div id="gallery" class="gallery">
<figure class="galery-item">
    <figcaption>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="galery-item">
    <figcaption>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="galery-item">
    <figcaption>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="galery-item">
    <figcaption>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure class="galery-item">
    <figcaption>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </figcaption>
</figure>   
</div>
```

Comment: That was just a typo error, wordpress is generating gallery, so everything is like in your code. Maybe the problem is that I call two masonry functions, for . gallery and .masonry-container, how should I do that. Also this error only shows on one page, not others. Actually sorry for not doing this sooner, but here is page that error is on, I completely forgot its online. http://outdoors.ga/wp/photos

Comment: One thing I see is you are loading jQuery twice, which can be a problem.this is the second one you should remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

Comment: The first one is wordpress called, and if I remove mine, jquery-latest-min.js, everything stops working.You can also enter in any post and see that masonry works fine, but only for this page doesn't.